# Flutter plugin package minification

Tags: flutter, dart, obfuscation

I've developed a plugin package that's compatible with both mobile platforms, Android and iOS. Since I'll be distributing this package to others, I'm looking to obfuscate the Dart code to enhance its security and make it unreadable, similar to the minification process used for JavaScript in web applications or AAR files in Android apps. I'm aware of the option to convert it into Ahead-of-Time (AOT) compilation, but I have dependencies tied to the Flutter package 'package:flutter/services.dart'. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or ideas on how to achieve this desired level of code obfuscation.